# split a number into equal part

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a for loop and i want to show the numbers equal parts.

Here is my code-

```
for($j = 1; $j <= 8; $j++){
    echo ($j%4)."<br/>";
}
```

I want output like-

```
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: try  echo (($j%4)+1). Add +1 to the modulo

Comment: It shows.. 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the solution:

```
<?php
for($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
    echo ($j % 4 + 1)."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($j = 0; $j <= 8; $j++){
    echo (($j%4)+1)."<br/>";
}
```

Add +1 to the modulo

Comment: remove the `<=` its `<` only

Comment: Should i start from 0??

Answer (score 1):

3 mall modification needed on your code:
1 - start loop from 0;
2 - end loop with <8;
3- add +1 to modulo

```
for($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
   echo ($j%4+1)."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write this

```
    for($j = 0; $j < 8; $j++){
    echo ($j % 4 + 1)."<br/>";
}
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach for repeating any array:

```
function array_repeat(array $v, int $n) {
  $ret = array();
  while ($n>0) {
     $ret = array_merge($ret,  $v);
     $n-=1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Your output can be generated with:

```
print_r (array_repeat(range(1,4),2));
```